# Why doesn't my script work with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to make a little "game" and for some reason, if I try and get the `checked` of a checkbox, my script will flip out... sometimes it works, sometimes it just stops executing. Is there some sort of an error I missed?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
var check = "showcheck";
var number = 1234;
var lvl = 1;
var oldlvl = 1;
var multiplier = 10000;
var start = 1;

function exefunction() {
    document.getElementById("boxv").focus();
    if (check == "showcheck") {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "What was the number?";
        document.getElementById("num").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("box").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("boxv").focus();
        check = "checknum";
    }
    else if (check == "checknum") {
        if (document.getElementById("boxv").value == number) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "CORRECT!";
            document.getElementById("boxv").style.color = "#00DD00";
            document.getElementById("boxv").value = number;
            document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = "Level: " + lvl;
            lvl++;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("boxv").value != number) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "INCORRECT!";
            document.getElementById("boxv").style.color = "#DD0000";
            document.getElementById("boxv").value = number;
            document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = "Level: " + lvl;
            if (lvl>1) {lvl--;}
            loselife();
        }
        check = "showmem";
    }
    else if (check == "showmem") {
        if (lvl == oldlvl + 10) {
            oldlvl = lvl;
            multiplier = multiplier * 10;
            document.getElementById("boxv").maxLength = multiplier.toString().length - 1;
        }
        else if (lvl < oldlvl) {
            oldlvl = lvl - 10;
            multiplier = multiplier / 10;
            document.getElementById("boxv").maxLength = multiplier.toString().length - 1;
        }
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * multiplier / 10 * 9) + multiplier / 10;
        document.getElementById("boxv").style.color = "#000000";
        document.getElementById("boxv").value = "";
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Memorize this number: ";
        document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = number;
        document.getElementById("num").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
        check = "showcheck";
    }
}

function loselife(){
    var life = 4;
    var hearts = "&#9829; ";
    alert(document.getElementById("lifebox").checked);
}
function submitenter() {
    var keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    if (keycode == 13) {
        if (start === 0) {exefunction();}
        else {startfunc();}
    }
    if (keycode < 47 || keycode > 58) {
        return false;
    }
}

function startfunc() {
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = '<input name="" type="button" value="OK" onClick="exefunction()"/>';
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = "Level: " + lvl;
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Memorize this number: ";
    document.getElementById("num").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("boxv").value = "";
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
    if (document.getElementById("lifecheck").checked === true) {
        document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = "&#9829; &#9829; &#9829; &#9829; &#9829; ";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("lifecheck").checked === false) {
        document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("timercheck").checked === true) {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "3:00";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("timercheck").checked === false) {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "";
    }
    start = 0;
}

function tests() {
    alert(lfckv);
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#level, #life, #timer{
    color: #666;
}
* {
    text-align: center;
}
#num {
    display: none;
}
#num {
    font-size: x-large;
}
#body {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
body {
    background-color: #6FF;
}
</style></head>
<body onKeyPress="return submitenter()" >
<div id="body">
<span id="level"></span>
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="200" height="50" align="center" valign="middle"><span id="message">What level would you like to begin at?</span></td>
    <td width="200" height="50" align="center" valign="middle"><span id="num">1234</span><span id="box"><input type="text" id="boxv" maxlength="4" value="1"/></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="200" id="life"><label><input id="lifecheck" type="checkbox" >Lives</label></td>
    <td id="button"><input type="button" value="OK" onClick="startfunc()"/></td>
    <td width="200" id="timer"><label><input id="timercheck" type="checkbox" >Timer</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input name="" type="button" onClick="tests()" value="tests()">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anything in the javascript console? "flip out" isn't exactly a useful diagnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahah! I figured out the problem. Apparently, when I set the visibility of the checkbox to none, it also set the checkvalue to null for some reason. I had expected it to keep the checkvalue, but for some reason it does not.

Answer (score 0):

`lifebox` isnt defined in the `loselife()` function. Plus, also check the `test()` function, that `alert()` statement has a variable that isnt defined.

If you are using Google chrome (or any other browser that can help you debug), I would suggest you to debug through your lines of code.

Comment: in chrome, all I get is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null"

Comment: Sean, perhaps you meant to do `document.getElementById("lifecheck")` not `"lifebox"`?  That's the main point here.  Also, Chrome and IE8's dev tools and Firebug all have "break on error" options that you can use to see where exactly this error occurs and perhaps figure out what variables are what at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off using simple equality for checking the state of your checkboxes, because I'm pretty the outcome is not a Boolean.

So it would be something like that :

```
if (document.getElementById("lifecheck").checked == true) {
```

or simply

```
if (document.getElementById("lifecheck").checked) {
```

instead of

```
if (document.getElementById("lifecheck").checked === true) {
```